# Is swearing an oath saying "if I do such and such, I will become a kafir" valid?

Tags: sin, kufr, evil-thoughts

I was alone and then I got a thought that if I do this sin (masturbation) then that means I don't believe in Allah and then I don't know why I just gave in to the temptation and started masturbating.

Does that make me kaffir?

I still pray and do dikr and worship Allah but I get these kind of thoughts that if I didn't do this and that, then I'm a kaffir and I don't know what to do.

Comment: You can read this fatwa: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/6262/he-said-may-the-curse-of-allaah-be-upon-me-if-i-smoke-another-cigarette-then-he-smoked-again

Answer (score 0):

Allah knows the best. But I could find something which is very close to this topic.

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>   Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "When an adulterer commits illegal sexual intercourse, then he is not a believer at the time he is doing it; and when somebody drinks an alcoholic drink, then he is not believer at the time of drinking, and when a thief steals, he is not a believer at the time when he is stealing; and when a robber robs and the people look at him, then he is not a believer at the time of doing it." Abu Huraira in another narration, narrated the same from the Prophet (ﷺ) with the exclusion of robbery. [Sahih Bukhari Vol. 8, Book 81, Hadith 763](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/86/1)

Other versions are [this](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/40/20) and the one below

> He (saw) also said: "If a man commits zina, faith comes out of him and hovers over him like a cloud, then when he stops, faith returns to him." Narrated by Abu Dawood (4960) and al-Tirmidhi (2625);